# vb.net variable declaration what is best practice

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

What is the best practice to declare instance of  objects in vb.net?

Dim Person1 as Person = new Person()

OR

Dim Person1 as new Person()

Comment: There is no difference. It's a matter of preference.

Comment: Enjoy being a VB programmer!  In C# you have to go with the first one, so personally I always use the second - just because I can.

Comment: As Ric says, it's a matter of preference. Whatever you do make sure you do it consistently though, so there's no question as to why you use option 1 in some places and option 2 in others.

Comment: @Steve Did you accidentally choose the wrong one?  That's not really a duplicate.  That question is about whether or not to specify the type.  This question is about using the `As New` vs. `= New` syntax.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference between the two.  In C#, there is no equivalent to the `As New` syntax, so often you will see C# programmers choosing the first option either out of ignorance or simply out of familiarity.

Sometimes, however, it is necessary to specify the type, for instance if you want to type your variable as an interface or as a base class:

```
Dim person1 As IPerson = New Person()
```

Or

```
Dim person1 As PersonBase = New Student()
```

It's also worth mentioning that the `As New` syntax existed in VB6, but it had a slightly different meaning.  In .NET, `As New` sets the starting value for the variable.  In VB6, it made the variable "auto-instantiate".  In VB6, if you declared a variable `As New`, it would automatically instantiate a new object each time you used the variable when it equals `Nothing`.  For instance:

```
'This is VB6, not VB.NET
Dim person1 As New Person
MsgBox person1.Name  ' person1 is set to a new Person object because it is currently Nothing
Set person1 = Nothing
MsgBox person1.Name  ' person1 is set to a second new Person object because it is currently Nothing
```

In VB.NET, it doesn't do that.  In VB.NET, if you set the variable to `Nothing`, it stays that way until you set it to something else, for instance:

```
'This is VB.NET
Dim person1 As New Person()  ' person1 is immediately set to a new Person object
MessageBox.Show(person1.Name)
person1 = Nothing
MessageBox.Show(person1.Name)   ' Throws an exception because person1 is Nothing
```

Comment: Good point about interface/abstract classes.

Comment: You need that to use the full power of polymorphism and just because to be always aware of that i prefer the second one.

Comment: @ruedi Agreed.  I'm sure you're not alone in that regard.  I use to feel the same way, but I have relaxed my position on that.  I practice DI, as much as possible, in all my code, so usually I have interfaces for everything anyway.  However, when it comes to DTO's, it's pointless to have an interface, and it's very uncommon to be concerned with inheritance when dealing with DTO's, so usually for those I now just take the convenient route and declare them `As New`.  It's also very handy when declaring auto-properties.